# is it safe to turn recycling off in Default Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, application-pool

I have app that has few schedule tasks that get initiated at application start. These task execute the actions and then sleep for X amount of time. This works perfectly fine except for the task that run sleep longer then the default time set for recycling in the application pool.

Its a small application only intended for internal use. The app at most will only have 10-15 people logged in at the same time and the server only has this app hosted on it.

I was wondering if its  safe to turn off recycling ?

Comment: In general I think that would be a bad idea. Web applications aren't really meant to manage long running processes. You'd be better off actually creating a *scheduled task* on the OS, or create a Windows service that the application could communicate with. Just my $0.02. Maybe... instead of sleeping, could you log the last time the task was executed, and just check if it's been `x` time since the last time it ran, to see if it's time to initiate it again?

Comment: @Cory Hmm that might work ... Thanks. I will look into window services as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will tell you something from experience.

We do not recycling the pools and the sites run perfectly with out any issue ! The only time that we recycle pools is usual on next reboot.

Maybe in a share environment where many different programmers runs under the same pool, sites with problems and forgotten to close handlers the recycle is a must.

But inside a controlled environment where you are in control for what are running on the pool, are tested that have no this issue, not throw handled of exception, the recycle is not needed.

PS: *If the asp.net is so bad that needs every now and then a reboot, then I will change language*. Of course is not, is very stable and good language that can run for days (if not for ever) if the program is good and well designed. And this is from real life, with real sites, real server - not just theory.

Comment: @keshav I replay to the question `I was wondering if its safe to turn off recycling ?` and not argue if this is the best way for what you do.

Comment: Before being able to turn off recycling altogether, we once had some weeks of WinDbg'ing, before we tracked down all memory leaks that prevented us from doing so. In our case, we had issues with heavy WCF traffic of large messages (several MBs per response).